# Please Help. Variable not being interpolated in Net :: SCP

Tags: perl, telnet, scp

This code telnets to a remote machine, fetches a latest directory. Then the latest folder name is stored into a variable then scp from remote to local machine happens. But the scp part is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Net::Telnet;
use Net::SCP::Expect;

$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10, Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->open('192.168.12.123');
$telnet->login("liam", "thegrey");

@output = $telnet->waitfor('/\$ $/i');
my @lines=$telnet->cmd('ls');

print"\t\tLOGIN IN SUCESS!!\n\n\n";

$telnet->cmd('cd vault');


print "\t\tThe latest file is >\n";

my @update;

@update=$telnet->cmd(
   'ls -l| grep Latest| tail -5 | head -2 | tail -1|tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f9');

my $found=join("",@update);
print "$found"; #The required value is printed here.

my $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(user=>'liam',password=>'thegrey');

#The $found variable is not being interpolated.
$scpe->scp("192.168.12.123:/root/vault/$found/latest/movie.mkv",
   "/root/ashesh_assignment/movie.mkv");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not true. if `$found` contains the value `xxx`, then the string literal

```
 "192.168.12.123:/root/vault/$found/latest/movie.mkv"
```

produces the string

```
 192.168.12.123:/root/vault/xxx/latest/movie.mkv
```

Now, it wouldn't surprise me if `$found` contained a newline which would create an *odd* path. Maybe a `chomp` is in order?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the output/ error I am getting is >

192.168.12.123:/root/vault//latest/movie.mkv

its coming just blank.

Comment: @Ashesh Are you sure there isn't anything else going on in your code?

Comment: I stand by what I said. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @AKHolland the code is working fine. It was strange for me that how the variable is not being interpolated. Anyways I used file-handling to solve this and it worked.

Comment: I shall repeat again. The variable was being interpolated. If you think it isn't, it's because the tools you were using the view the string (e.g. the terminal) did not accurately represent the string.

Comment: `"192.168.12.123:/root/vault/$found/latest/movie.mkv"` gets compiled to the same thing as `"192.168.12.123:/root/vault/".$found."/latest/movie.mkv"` so you are repeatedly claiming that the one of the two instances of the concatenation operator decided to replace its second argument with an empty string before perform the concatenation. No, the mistake is entirely in your own analysis. When you ask for help and someone points out you made a mistake, you should listen. It's why you aasked them for help in the first place.